# Quantum entanglement and information transfer faster than light

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, faster-than-light

According to quantum entanglement theory, if the spins of two particles are in superposition and then spin of one particle is observed, the spin of the other particle is determined immediately. While it also says information cannot be transmitted faster than light using this.

At first glance, however, physical influences are spreading to other spaces faster than light, so it could be used to convey information.

For example, consider the following thought experiment.

Think of a planet P that is one light year away from Earth. (Assuming it is in the same inertial frame as Earth, so it shares the same clock (or calendar) as Earth.)

According to the theory of relativity, it is impossible to transmit information faster than light, so the results of a sporting event held on Earth on January 1, 2021 will not be available until January 1, 2022 to the people on the planet P.

However, to inform this immediately, we create the following device:

Prepare the particles A1, ..., A100, B1, ..., B100 from the earth and entangle A1 and B1, A2 and B2, ..., A100 and B100, respectively. Observing the spin of each particle in the x direction, one of each A1 or B1 is in the + and one is in the - state. Here we can say that A1 is in the + state without lose of generality (if it is the opposite, change only the names of the two particles), and that all A1, ..., A100 are in the + state, and all B1, ..., B100 are in the - state.

Now let's leave A-particles on Earth and send B-particles to planet P on December 31, 2019. Then on January 1, 2021, the B-particles are all arriving at planet P, with the spin in the x direction still -. In other words, if you look at the x-direction spin of B on the planet P, it's all minus, because both of the A and B's x-direction spins are undecided.

However, if we collapse all the x-direction spins of A-particles on Earth (for example, observe the y-direction spins), then all of the x-direction spins of B-particles will also collapse, resulting in a superposition of + and - state. And then when we observe the spins in the x direction of the B-particles on planet P, we see + and - in roughly half the ratio.

Using this, we can transfer information on Earth immediately to the planet P. To illustrate, in Korea and Japan's soccer game on Earth on January 1, 2021, if Korea wins, just leave the A-particles on Earth unchanged, and if Japan defeats collapse all the x-direction spins of the A-particles. Then we observed the x-direction spins of B-particles on planet P on January 2, 2021. If they were all aligned with -, Korea would have won, and if + and - were mixed properly, Japan would have won.

But of course, this would be an impossible device because it would violate the causality in relativism, but I don't know where it went wrong.

Please let me know what assumptions or steps were wrong in the above experiment.

Comment: Hi Ramanasa - If Korea wins the spins on Planet P remain minus (-) but how do the Planet P people know what caused that? Planet Earth people may have lost their particles somehow and can't communicate that event faster than light speed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you’re assuming you’ll know what the state of the entangled particle is before you’ve measured it, and thus that you’ll know it has “changed”. Unfortunately, in order to know for certain what state any of the particles is in, one must collapse the state, thereby breaking the entanglement. Thus, one cannot measure either of the entangled particles (to know what the states are) and then “change” one to affect the other via entanglement.

Answer (score 2):

You assumed that:

- A1 is in the x+ state
- B1 is in the x- state
- A1 and B1 are entangled

These three assumptions cannot simultaneously be true.